# Codesniffer validation of @mainpage

Tags: 7

When I add an @mainpage block to a .module file this file doesn't validate when I run phpcs.

I always get

```
ERROR   | [ ] Missing short description in doc comment
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Edit: Code example:


`/**
 * @mainpage
 * Foobar module, provides foo functionality.
 *
 * Topics:
 * - @link foobar_menu Generates the admin menu for this module @endlink
 *
 * The foobar module fetches data from a webservice, no data is held in Drupal.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function foobar_menu() {
  // Do stuff.
}`

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like more of a question about Codesniffer than Drupal - can you confirm whether it raises the same error with the same comment style in a non-Drupal project? If it does, this isn't the right place to ask. If it doesn't, we're probably going to need more details to be able to help

Comment: @immoreel Paste your relevant code, please.

Comment: Added edits, above